# How can I combine a column from one dataframe into another based on the results of "isin"?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two XLS sheets that I've read into two dataframes. I would like to find the intersection between the two, where the contents of one df column is contained in a specific column in the other df.  And from that intersection, I'd like to create a new df that contains the intersection AND the values from a particular column in one of those dfs.

I cannot figure out what function in Pandas to get that intersection to work, and to include the data from the additional column.

This is what I tried to get the intersection:

```
import pandas as pd
test_file = '/Users/Bill/Box Sync/Documents/Jupyter/test_data.xlsx'
# read in the xls sheets
prj_df = pd.read_excel(test_file, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
opp_df = pd.read_excel(test_file, sheet_name = 'Sheet2')
# intersect the sheets
report_df = opp_df[opp_df['opp'].isin(prj_df['opp numbers'])]
```

...but as you'll see below, report_df only includes the rows where the contents of "opp" and "opp numbers" match exactly.  I need something that is more like the Python "in" keyword when looking for a string in a string.

Here is some test data:

```
prj_df:

   Project            opp numbers          URL
0  Project 1 title    ab-cdefg;12-34567    http://1.2.3.4/abc
1  project 2 title    MJ-98733             http://1.2.3.4/UJUJUJUJ
2  Project 3 title    No code              http://1.2.3.4/99a
3  Project A title    01-PKL23             http://1.2.3.4/azzz
4  project B title    44-0098876           http://test.133
5  project c title    342-0981;98-09913    http://2.3.4.5/iiihh
6  project 99 title   25-AAAJJ12;99-49494  http://1.2.3.4/ghhi
7  project 303 title  77-AUDIJJ            http://1.2.3.4/def

opp_df:

0  opp        product     price
1  98-09913   widget1     123.55
2  66-99999   widget2     44.99
3  AB-DEFFF1  widget3     2345.5
4  01-PKL23   item a      9990
5  77-AUDIJJ  item b      84.56
6  KK-KIEW89  product 99  22.99
7  WE-24422   name 123    1.99
8  12-34567   stuff 1     395.5

report_df:

   opp        product     price
3  01-PKL23   item a      9990.00
4  77-AUDIJJ  item b      84.56
```

....but that data in report_df isn't complete: I also need row 1 and row 8 to show up because the 'opp' values from those rows are also contained in prj_df.

Now, in addition to getting the intersection correct, what I'd like to do is to add the values from the URL and Project columns of prj_df onto the end of report_df. Since I've been using the openpyxl library, my brain is only tuned to iterating through the sheet/dataframe and searching prj_df for the values instead of using the isin intersection I already did.

Is there a way to a) get that intersection to work, and b) pull in the Project and URL values into that intersected dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

This is easier done with pandas merge function. But to do that you have to first split your values to rows using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51752361/9081267) function.

After that you can do an [`inner merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
prj_df = explode_str(df, 'opp numbers', sep=';')
print(prj_df)

             Project opp numbers                      URL
0    Project 1 title    ab-cdefg       http://1.2.3.4/abc
0    Project 1 title    12-34567       http://1.2.3.4/abc
1    project 2 title    MJ-98733  http://1.2.3.4/UJUJUJUJ
2    Project 3 title     No code       http://1.2.3.4/99a
3    Project A title    01-PKL23      http://1.2.3.4/azzz
4    project B title  44-0098876          http://test.133
5    project c title    342-0981     http://2.3.4.5/iiihh
5    project c title    98-09913     http://2.3.4.5/iiihh
6   project 99 title  25-AAAJJ12      http://1.2.3.4/ghhi
6   project 99 title    99-49494      http://1.2.3.4/ghhi
7  project 303 title   77-AUDIJJ       http://1.2.3.4/def
```

**Now we can merge:**

```
report_df = opp_df.merge(prj_df[['opp numbers']], 
                         left_on='opp', 
                         right_on='opp numbers').drop('opp numbers', axis=1)

print(report_df)
         opp  product    price
0   98-09913  widget1   123.55
1   01-PKL23   item a  9990.00
2  77-AUDIJJ   item b    84.56
3   12-34567  stuff 1   395.50
```

**Function used from linked answer**

```
def explode_str(df, col, sep):
    s = df[col]
    i = np.arange(len(s)).repeat(s.str.count(sep) + 1)
    return df.iloc[i].assign(**{col: sep.join(s).split(sep)})
```

Comment: Thanks, Erfan. I'm getting an error walkback from the arange call; the error says "error: nothing to repeat at position 0" out of the sre_parse.py module.  Does this code expect that every value in the column will have that separator?  I cut down the sheet to one row; the column value in my test is "09-ABCS1AR + 01-1234567", and that throws that error.